# How to support media type versioning using Camel Rest DSL

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I'm looking for a solution to using the Camel Rest DSL when versioning my REST API using media type versioning.  See https://www.narwhl.com/2015/03/the-ultimate-solution-to-versioning-rest-apis-content-negotiation/ for details on what I am trying to accomplish.

For example, if I have two versions of a Store object (V1_0 and V2_0).

```
.post('/').description('Create a new store').type(Store_V1_0).outType(Store_V1_0)
    .consumes('application/x.canopy.store+json; version=1.0, application/x.canopy.store+json; version=2.0')
    .produces('application/x.canopy.store+json; version=1.0, application/x.canopy.store+json; version=2.0' )
    .param().name('body').type(body).description('The store to create').endParam()
    .route()
        .to('log:com.acme.api.store?level=INFO&showHeaders=true')
    .endRest()
```

Notice that I have specified multiple media types in the "consumes"/"produces".  However, I'm limited to a single class in the "type"/"outType".

If I attempt multiple "post('/')" lines, I receive a "Duplicate verb detected in rest-dsl" error.  Is there a way I can bind media types to POJO(s)?

Any suggestions on how to handle versioning my REST API using media types is welcomed.

EDIT: I am also trying to generate the spec for Swagger and would like to be able to see a different "Example Value" in Swagger UI based on the chosen content-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`consumes`, `produces`, `type`, `outType` are only useful to generate the swagger spec. You can accept/unmarshal, process and marshal back to any format you want after the `route()` directive in your rest definition:

Something like that:

```
.post('/').description('Create a new store')
    .param().name('body').type(body).description('The store to create').endParam()
    .route()
        .to('log:com.acme.api.store?level=INFO&showHeaders=true')
        .choice()
          .when(header(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE).isEqualTo("application/x.canopy.store+json; version=1.0"))
            .unmarshal(Store_V1_0)
            .process(v1Processor)
          .when(header(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE).isEqualTo("application/x.canopy.store+json; version=1.2"))
            .unmarshal(Store_V2_0)
            .process(v2Processor)
        .end()
        .process(doSomethingElse)
        .marshal().json()
    .endRest()
```

Comment: I will amend my question, as I should have included that I am also trying to generate the spec for Swagger UI.  I was hoping to be able to see a different "Example Value" in Swagger UI based off of the chosen content-type. You have definitely helped me with part of my problem.  Any additional help on the Swagger side would be appreciated!

Comment: Appears I should have read the Swagger 2.0 spec more closely. What I am trying to achieve is not yet supported, but it appears that it will be in 2.1. 

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/146

Going to accept Strelok's answer.